# jbpm6 - build.xml:508: jboss did not start within 5 minutes

Tags: java, xml, ant, jboss

I am new to jbpm and trying to learn jbpm 6, so i downloaded and following the steps which provided document.I was trying to demo using

ant install.demo its working upto install jbpm modular.

I am set the environment of my System is

Note : i am  using windows 7 - 64 bit.

```
      Java -version is 1.7

      ANT -Version is 1.9.3
```

JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45

ANT_HOME=D:\ant

PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ANT_HOME%\bin;

I am Install the demo using command in command prompt is          ant install.demo

```
 Then am starting the demo using ant start.demo
```

Then am getting Error as:       BUILD FAILED C:\jbpm-installer\build.xml:508: JBoss application server did not start within 5 minutes

To avoid this i did some things, as i read the things from google, by increasing the time out would help ful in build.xml when  JBPM 6 at the line number 504.

I am change the port number in build.xml to avoid the conflicts.

Even though i am following above conditions again it repeating the Same Error.

Can Any One ? For Solutions Under JBPM 6 Version............ Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The solution was reinstalling java to another version. Moreover, now I have 2 version installed: 32-bit jre and 64-bit jdk in the same moment.

Comment: could you please elaborate on that answer ? Do we install 32-bit or 64-bit jdk ?